# Minecraft Update Stuck

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

When i install minecraft 1.16.5 update, it gets stuck at "downloading rt.jar". I even deleted .minecraft and installed it again but it got stuck again. Theres nothing wrong with my internet and i even turned off every vpn and antivirus. It still gets stuck at "rt.jar". What do i do to fix it? Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the ACTUAL minecraft client (from minecraft.net) or a different client? If its a different client we can't really help you.

Comment: No. I was using a different launcher (SKLauncher). I guess i will try deleteing .minecraft and downloading it again. thanks for answering tho.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting .minecraft and installing it again should fix the problem. If it didnt work for 1st time (just like me) you should actually delete .minecraft itself and download it again 2nd time. That should fix the problem.

Comment: Remember to use the official Minecraft launcher!

Comment: Deleting your .minecraft folder will remove all other installations and saved worlds. Don't do this without backing up the folder first!